# XState: Types of property 'actions' are incompatible

Tags: typescript, xstate

I am writing my first XState-driven app in TypeScript, with the FAST framework from Microsoft. I am getting a compile-time error on my `states.loading.invoke.onDone.actions` property, that looks like this:

```
export const questions = {
  initial: 'loading',
  states: {
    loading: {
      invoke: {
        id: 'loadQuestions',
        src: (context, event) => fetchQuestions,
        onDone: {
          target: 'asking',
          actions: assign({
            questions: (context, event: any) => event.data // this is generating an error
          })
        },
        onError: {}
      },
      tags: ['loading'],
    },
    asking: {
      always: [{
        target: '#search',
        cond: 'questionsExhausted'
      }],
      on: {
        QUESTION_ANSWERED: ''
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The machine looks like this:

```
const states = {questions, search};

const initial = 'questions';

interface EventsSearchContext  {
  questions: Question[];
}

const context = {
  questions: []
};

const config = {
  schema: {
    context: {} as EventsSearchContext
  },
  id: 'eventsSearch',
  initial,
  context,
  states
}

const eventsSearchMachine = createMachine(config);
```

and my `search` states look like this:

```
export const search = {
  id: 'search',
  initial: 'performingSearch',
  states: {
    performingSearch: {},
    displayingResults: {}
  }
};
```

Just a basic outline at the moment, but this error is being generated:

```
Types of property 'onDone' are incompatible.
  Type '{ target: string; actions: AssignAction<unknown, any>; }' is not assignable to type 'string | SingleOrArray<TransitionConfig<EventsSearchContext, DoneInvokeEvent<any>>> | undefined'.
    Type '{ target: string; actions: AssignAction<unknown, any>; }' is not assignable to type 'TransitionConfig<EventsSearchContext, DoneInvokeEvent<any>>'.
      Types of property 'actions' are incompatible.
        Type 'AssignAction<unknown, any>' is not assignable to type 'Actions<EventsSearchContext, DoneInvokeEvent<any>> | undefined'.
          Type 'AssignAction<unknown, any>' is missing the following properties from type 'Action<EventsSearchContext, DoneInvokeEvent<any>>[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 29 more.
```

There is only one `onDone`, so hopefully it's clear where this is coming from.

There are no solutions on the web anywhere, but the [troubleshooting page](https://xstate.js.org/docs/guides/typescript.html#assign-action-behaving-strangely) does mention a similar issue. I tried it, but it doesn't work unfortunately. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

When trying to reproduce, I found a solution that worked for me which is using the services schema property like in the [official documentation](https://xstate.js.org/docs/guides/typescript.html#typing-promise-services)

Something like the following could work I think:

```
import { createMachine, assign } from 'xstate'
    
interface EventsSearchContext  {
  questions: Question[];
}

const eventsSearchMachine = createMachine({
  schema: {
    context: {} as EventsSearchContext,
  },
  id: 'eventsSearch',
  initial: 'questions',
  context: {
    questions: []
  },
  states: {
    questions: {
      initial: 'loading',
      states: {
        loading: {
          invoke: {
            id: 'loadQuestions',
            src: 'fetchQuestions',
            onDone: {
              target: 'asking',
              actions: 'assignQuestion'
            },
            onError: 'asking',
          },
          tags: ['loading'],
        },
        asking: {
          always: [{
            target: '#search',
            cond: 'questionsExhausted'
          }],
          on: {
            QUESTION_ANSWERED: ''
          }
        }
      }
    },
    search: {
      id: 'search',
      initial: 'performingSearch',
      states: {
        performingSearch: {},
        displayingResults: {}
      }
    }
  }
}, {
  services: {
    fetchQuestions,
  },
  actions: {
    assignQuestion: assign({
      questions: (context, event: any) => event.data
    })
  }
})
```